# Tasks Scheduler Windows High Availability

Tags: windows, cluster, high-availability, task-scheduler

What is the best way to put in place «tasks scheduler» with high availability under Windows?

Currently, the tasks are planned on a single server, which is a problem when the server reboot (for many reasons)

Is there a Cluster system to resolve that?

Typically two servers, one master, the other slave and when the master is no longer available, then the task is taken over by the slave who becomes master?

I read [this link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/failure-clustering/how-to-configure-clustered-tasks-with-windows-server-failover/ba-p/371784?%20lightbox-message-images-371784=90376iE3580C0450F14077) which could respond to my problem, but there is no indication of how to create the cluster.

Comment: You are aware of the cluster task scheduler in a windows cluster? If you HAVE a cluster that could be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You create Windows Failover Cluster.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/create-failover-cluster

2. You configure clustered tasks.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/failover-clustering/how-to-configure-clustered-tasks-with-windows-server-failover/ba-p/371784

P.S. You might want to do some shared storage for your WSFC instance, but there are so many different ways to do that...

Comment: thank you.
do you know a « app service » in the Market Place Azure avoiding the deployment of two servers ?